# Is there a way to replace the contents of two variables with each other('s)?

Tags: autohotkey

Without using a third variable for temporary storage and variables contents rotation? Such as a special equal(-sign) operator?

Efficient code is beautiful code.

Answer (score 2):

Readable code is beautiful code, so there really isn't a better way than using a temporary variable.

If you really wanted to do it you could use a few xors.

Since

```
X := X XOR Y
Y := X XOR Y
X := X XOR Y
```

switches the two variables. You can do xor with ^ in autohotkey.

However, do compare it to:

```
c = a
a = b
b = c
```

It's just as long, but the using a temporary variable is much more readable. And the cost of creating a variable isn't going to matter, no matter the system you are making (especially if you are making it in AutoHotKey).

Comment: It's a nice trick, but I can't stress this enough: don't do it. It's horrible unreadable, and in no way better than c = a; a = b; b = c.

Comment: Technically it works.but it is not as efficient as standard assignment. Moreover if one of the variables will be changed after the first assignment, then both of them are corrupted.

Comment: Yes. Which is why you shouldn't do it. As I said, using a temporary variable is short, readable and fast. It's a good solution. The other way is just answering the question.

Comment: @NiteCyper this is shortest you can use XOR: x ^= y ... but as Astrogat said it's not more efficient, even it looks to be.